# Why doesn't Simplify use my own TransformationFunction?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I define a simple `TransformationFunctions` via:

```
tfTest[e_] := e /. {x^2 -> Hold[x*x]}
```

and try to use it with `Simplify` like this:

```
Simplify[x^2, TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, tfTest}]
```

> x^2 (*output*)

The output is of course the input without `tfTest` applied to it. Interestingly a `TransformationFunction` like

```
tfTest[e_] := e /. {x^2 -> 2}
```

is working.

I tried monitoring the output via using a `ComplexityFunction`

```
cf = (Print[#]; LeafCount[#] + Count[#, _Symbol, {0, -1}]) &;
ClearSystemCache[]
FullSimplify[x^2, TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, tfTest}, 
 ComplexityFunction -> cf]
```

but I could not make sense of the output being an alternating sequence of the answer I would want and the unchanged input.

Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: Hint: `Simplify` tries to minimize `ComplexityFunction`.

Comment: Makes sense that it tries to minimize `ComplexityFunction`. For some reason I was naive enough to think that manually supplied `TransformationFunctions` have absolute priority.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
tfTest[e_] := e /. {x^2 -> Hold[x*x]}

f[e_] := LeafCount[e] +
  100 Count[e, _Power, {0, Infinity}]

Simplify[x^2,
 TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, tfTest},
 ComplexityFunction -> f]

(*  Hold[x x]  *)
```